# Perform calculation in higher order component in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a react application, where I want to perform a conditional check rather a given prop of a certain percentage is a given value.

As of now, I render a Match component in my main component like such

```
                <Match 
                inputName={this.state.inputName}
                inputSname={this.state.inputSname}
                percentage={this.state.percentage}
                result={this.state.result}
                show={this.state.showResult}
                />
```

I want to check the percentage of the match component, so I have a MatchWrapper component which is a higher order component, giving an extra prop down to my next component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
const MatchWrapper = WrappedComponent =>{
return class MatchWrapper extends Component{    
    state = {
        type: ''
    } 

    componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.percentage)
    let type = ''
        switch(this.props.percentage){
            case this.props.percentage > 75:
                type="succes";
                break;
            case this.props.percentage > 50 && 75 > this.props.percentage:
                type="mediocre";
                break;
            case this.props.percentage < 50:
                type="failure123";
                break;
        }
        this.setState({
            type: type
        })
    }
    render(){
    return(
     <div>
    <WrappedComponent type={this.state.type} {...this.props}/>
</div>
)
}
}
}
export default MatchWrapper;
```

in my match component (which is a functional component, and only displays values)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './Match.css';
import MatchWrapper from '../HOC/MatchWrapper'
import './Match.css';

const match = (props) =>{


console.log(props.show)
console.log(props.type)
return(
    <div>
{props.show ?
<div>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>{props.inputName} Du har sgu scoret en jackpot</p>
    <p>{props.inputSname} Er sgu en laks udover det sædvanelige!</p>
    <p>I har scorede hele {props.percentage} procent</p>
    <p>Jeg synes du skulle invitere hende på data med det samme</p>   
</div>  
: null} 
</div>
)
}
export default MatchWrapper(match)
```

Here I want to console.log the given prop type, but the calculation isn't correct, since it renders nothing OR the base case, if a default case is given in the switch statement. How can I improve my logic, so I correctly perform the calculation inside my HOC?

EDIT: i figured the issue is that my HOC does not receive any props, but I'm not sure as to why?

Love component that render match:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './Love.css'
import  Match from './Matches/Match'
import MatchWrapper from './HOC/MatchWrapper';

class Love extends Component{

    state= {
        inputName: '',
        inputSname: '',
        percentage: 0,
        result: '',
        showResult: false
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('hello')
    }

    findMatchHandler = () =>{
    axios.get(`https://love-calculator.p.mashape.com/getPercentage?fname=${this.state.inputName}&sname=${this.state.inputSname}`,{
        headers: {
           "X-Mashape-Key": "cZA91FBSWlmshegV4IsGJIcGoc3yp1Eq9cCjsnjMGOVB35Z1Ud",
           "Accept": "application/json"
        }
       }).then(res =>
           this.setState({
               name: res.data.fname,
               sName: res.data.sname,
               percentage: res.data.percentage,
               result: res.data.result,
               showResult: true
           })
           )
           }

render(){

      console.log(this.state.percentage)
      console.log(this.state.showResult)
        return(

            <div className={"main-div " + (this.state.percentage > 75 && this.state.showResult ? "match " : ' ') + (this.state.percentage > 50  && this.state.percentage < 75 && this.state.showResult === true ? 'semi ' : ' ') + (this.state.percentage < 50 && this.state.showResult ? 'no-match': '')}>

                    <button onClick={this.findMatchHandler}>Find love!</button>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.inputName} onChange={(event) => this.setState({inputName: event.target.value, showResult: false})} placeholder="enter your name"/>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.inputSname} onChange={(event) => this.setState({inputSname: event.target.value, showResult: false})} placeholder="enter your name"/>



                    <Match
                    inputName={this.state.inputName}
                    inputSname={this.state.inputSname}
                    percentage={this.state.percentage}
                    result={this.state.result}
                    show={this.state.showResult}
                    />
               </div>
        )
}
}
export default Love
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It receives the props just fine.

The problem is with your `switch` statement. Your `case` expressions result in `true` or `false` so that is what should be in the `switch`

```js
switch (true) {
  case this.props.percentage > 75:
    type = "succes";
    break;
  case this.props.percentage > 50 && 75 >= this.props.percentage:
    type = "mediocre";
    break;
  case this.props.percentage <= 50:
    type = "failure123";
    break;
}
```

(*also added `=` to the second and third cases so that there are no unhandled cases*)

Comment: I tried this, but i still don't recieve any props inside my code, i tried rendering this.props.children, and i got undefined...

Comment: @baileyhaldwin it works in my test at https://codesandbox.io/s/zqom48w1qp

Comment: @baileyhaldwin also show us what is in the `state` of the component that renders the `Match`.

Comment: Youre' right.. thats strange, i get the right props in the match component, but not in the MatchWrapper, i put the entire main component, love into the question

Comment: Now i know the issue... it's because  put my switch statement, in component did mou nt and the percentage is 0 initially, so it is never changed.. thank you for your help